# A problem in Trigonometry (Properties of Triangles)

Tags: trigonometry

How do I solve this problem on Properties of Triangles in Trigonometry?

> In any triangle ABC, prove that $$(b+c-a) \left( \cot {\frac {B}{2}} + \cot {\frac {C}{2}} \right) = 2a \cot \frac {A}{2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Use

$$\cot  \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)=\frac{s-a}{r}$$

$$\cot  \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)=\frac{s-b}{r}$$

$$\cot  \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)=\frac{s-c}{r}$$

where $2s=a+b+c$, $b+c-a=2s-2a=2(s-a)$, and $r$ is the inradius

$$(b+c-a)\left(\cot  \left(\frac{B}{2}\right)+\cot  \left(\frac{C}{2}\right)\right)=$$

$$(b+c-a)\left(\frac{s-b}{r}+\frac{s-c}{r}\right)=$$

$$(b+c-a)\left(\frac{2s-b-c}{r}\right)=2(s-a)\frac{a}{r}=$$

$$2a \cot  \left(\frac{A}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

**hint**: Use $a = 2R\sin A, b = 2R\sin B, c = 2R\sin C$, and $\sin X = 2\sin \left(\frac{X}{2}\right)\cos \left(\frac{X}{2}\right)$ for $X = A, B, C$. Also, rewrite $\cot \left(\frac{X}{2}\right) = \dfrac{\cos \left(\frac{X}{2}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{X}{2}\right)}$, $X = A, B, C$, and $\cos^2\left(\frac{X}{2}\right) = \dfrac{1+\cos X}{2}, X = A, B, C$. Then simplify both sides and you should get a nice expression for both sides and they are equal as well.

Comment: Not sure why this answer got down-vote!